# if data of current year not available show previous year

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a query to show data of present year and the rows in which data of current year is not present show previous year data but now the problem is that the companies which  have present year data available is showing previous year data as well

Database company_annual_data

```
 +--id--+---company_id----+----year-----+----number_of_shares_issued----+
+   1  +     20          +    2011     +              425              +
+   2  +     21          +    2011     +              425              +
+   3  +     22          +    2011     +              425              +
+   4  +     23          +    2011     +              425              +
+   5  +     21          +    2012     +              425              +
+   6  +     20          +    2012     +              425              +
+   7  +     23          +    2012     +              425              +
+   8  +     20          +    2013     +              425              +
```

Companies

```
+--id--+---company_name----+----category-----+
+  20  +     Company 1     +       2         +
+  21  +     Company 2     +       2         +
+  22  +     Company 3     +       2         +
+  23  +     Company 4     +       5         +
```

This is my query

```
$sql            = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE category = '36'");
    $total_count    = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    $companies = array();


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $companies[] = $row['id'];
    }

    $ids = join(', ', $companies);

    $sql1         = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT year FROM companies_annual_data WHERE company_id IN ($ids) ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 0, $total_count");
    $total_count1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
    $year     = array();

    $prev_val = null;       
    while($total_year = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
        if($total_year['year'] != $prev_val) {
            $year[] =  $total_year['year'];
        }
        $prev_val = $total_year['year'];    
    }

    $years      = join(', ', $year);
    $sql2       = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT DISTINCT number_of_shares_issued, year, company_id FROM companies_annual_data WHERE company_id IN ($ids) AND year IN ($years)");
    $prev_val_y = null;
    while($share_num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        if($share_num['year'] != date('Y')) {
            echo "Number Of Shares : " . $share_num['number_of_shares_issued'];
            echo " Year : " . $share_num['year'];
            echo " Company Id : " . $share_num['company_id'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```

This is the out put

```
Number Of Shares : 284125000 Year : 2015 Company Id : 348
Number Of Shares : 100000000 Year : 2015 Company Id : 351
Number Of Shares : 152098344 Year : 2015 Company Id : 356
Number Of Shares : 152098334 Year : 2016 Company Id : 356
Number Of Shares : 283500000 Year : 2015 Company Id : 366
Number Of Shares : 283500000 Year : 2016 Company Id : 366
```

That is wrong the output should be like this

```
Number Of Shares : 284125000 Year : 2015 Company Id : 348
Number Of Shares : 100000000 Year : 2015 Company Id : 351
Number Of Shares : 152098334 Year : 2016 Company Id : 356
Number Of Shares : 283500000 Year : 2016 Company Id : 366
```

Can anyone help me out with this please

Comment: Seems to me if you max the year and group by no of shares and comany ID you'd get your desired results.  I don't see why you have 3 queries when 1 would suffice using joins.

Comment: is because want to sum data by companie industry like get company data within 1 industry i do not know how to make query so to making it simple i made this query :(

Comment: @xQbert can you help me out ?

Comment: See about JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question...

This will return the most recent year's data on record for each company provided
category is 36

```
SELECT CAD.num_of_Shares_Issued, CAD.`Year`, CAD.Company_ID
FROM Companies C
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(`year`) MYear, Company_ID 
            FROM company_Annual_data 
            GROUP BY Company_ID) SUB
 on SUB.CompanyID = C.Company_ID
LEFT JOIN Company_Annual_data CAD
 on C.ID = CAD.Company_ID
and SUB.MYear = CAD.`year`
WHERE  C.Category = 36
```

Comment: you got correct what i am loking for but i got an error  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: what that because of using caps etc ?

Comment: I'm weak in PHP; strong in SQL.  can we first make sure the SQL is working (getting the correct results in a DB query window) then jump into the PHP? (someone else may need to help with the PHP)

Comment: great it worked for me know thank you so very muuch can you explain me what exatcly you did if you can